# How do I override icons in Material UI DataGrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

We need to customize most of the icons used in the [DataGrid](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/) from Material UI. Reading the very limited docs, we cannot figure out how to do that.

The [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#icons-slots) talks about *slots* (but with no explanation on how to use those). There is a `icons` property, but we're not sure if `IconsOptions` is the same as slots. Regardless, we tried the following:

```js
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          icons={{
            ColumnMenuIcon: AcUnit
          }}
          />
      </div>
```

and the following:

```js
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          ColumnMenuIcon={AcUnit}
          />
      </div>
```

To no avail. We tried using `<AcUnit/>` instead, but no change. Tried reading the code but that did not really help either...

What is the proper way of doing this? If that is a standard way of doing things in either React or Material UI, where can we find some documentation?

Here is a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-datagrid-icons-override-ukzyk?file=/demo.js).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find this documented here: https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/components/#icons with the list of available icons to customize in the [documentation you noted](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid/#icons-slots). The example shows using the `components` prop to customize the icons.

The following syntax works:

```
        <DataGrid
          rows={rows}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={5}
          disableSelectionOnClick
          components={{
            ColumnMenuIcon: AcUnit
          }}
        />
```

[image: Edit Material DataGrid Icons Override]

Comment: Thank you Ryan! I feel honored... been seeing your name a lot on questions I look at on SO lately ;)